# excel vba fill column from 1 to N

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA code to autofill range A1:A10000 with numbers 1 to 10000 but without entering 1 in A1 and 2 in A2 to create a range.

Basically, I need a code that looks like this:

```
Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000")
(1,2).AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
```

Of course this does not work, but you get what it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing and reading to/from the worksheet are some of the slowest actions you can perform.  Writing time-efficient code means doing as much in memory as you can.

Try writing all your values into an array, then writing the whole thing to the worksheet in one shot, something like this:

```
Sub printRange(total As Integer)
Dim i, myRange() As Integer
ReDim myRange(1 To total)
    For i = 1 To total:
        myRange(i) = i
Next i

'Use Transpose to shift the 1d array into a column

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & UBound(myRange)).Value = _ 
Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myRange)

End Sub
```

For total = 10000, this pretty much runs instantly, even on a ten year old dinosaur desktop.

Comment: THIS is what I was looking for.

Comment: @PeterPeanut, I'm glad you found the help you needed.  As R3UK commented earlier, please consider accepting the answer and/or voting, as indicated in this explanation on how SO works.  http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim fillRange As Range
Dim i As Long

Set fillRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000")
With fillRange
    For i = .Cells(1, 1).Row To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).Row
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = i
    Next i
End With 'fillRange
```

Or with AutoFill :

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Range("A1").Value = 1
    Range("A2").Value = 2
    Range("A1:A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A10000")
End With 'Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Comment: Now, all these answers work. However, I thought that code would be faster if I can autofill range the get into for-to loop. I the speed is same, then forget it.

Comment: @PeterPeanut : AutoFill ain't that fast, you can compare the 2 options (I added code)! But please take a minute to discover how SO works (accepting answers and later voting) : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

this should be fast enough

you could use the following function

```
Function FillNumbers(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim nmbrs(1 To rng.Rows.Count)

    For i = 1 To UBound(nmbrs)
        nmbrs(i) = i
    Next
    FillNumbers = Application.Transpose(nmbrs)
End Function
```

in the following manner

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000")
    .Value = FillNumbers(.Cells)
End With
```

Comment: Nice, you beat me to it!  Great minds think alike.  +1 to you for speed, it took me a minute to remember to transpose it, I couldn't figure out why mine kept outputting 10000 lines of zeroes.

Comment: @SgtStens, no "great mind" at all on my part! just hundreds of "trial and error" (and, curiously, much more errors than trials!). But let's wait for Peter Peanut choice...

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a simple loop?

```
For i = 1 to 10000
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = i
Next i
```

Comment: Tim, sorry for the late answer. I would rather not use a simple loop because it would have to be run on 80 sheets and each sheet has about 20.000 lines. It would take too much time and I am trying to speed it up as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim fillRagne As Range
Set fillRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1000, 1))
For Each cell in fillRange
    cell.value = cell.Row
Next cell
```

Comment: I asked for an autofill because my code is running through about 70 sheets, and it takes about 10 minutes to run. So, I was wondering if autofill was faster then for-to loop. I tested it and it was not, so I guess, for-to remains.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also contain a explanation.